# wget download hdf file in a MODIS URL

Tags: linux, wget

I try to use wget to download a large amount of data from NASA MODIS dataset.
They provide data pool link, e.g. https://e4ftl01.cr.usgs.gov/MOLT/MOD11A2.061/2000.02.18/.

In the link, there are jpg, xml, and hdf files. I only need the **hdf** file.
If I run

```
wget https://e4ftl01.cr.usgs.gov/MOLT/MOD11A2.061/2000.02.18/ --user=XXX --password=XXX -P XXX/XXX/XXX
```

then, everything would be downloaded.

So, how to write this command to download only hdf files.
Thank you, best wishes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest following solution

```
wget --recursive --level=1 --accept hdf https://e4ftl01.cr.usgs.gov/MOLT/MOD11A2.061/2000.02.18/ --user=XXX --password=XXX -P XXX/XXX/XXX
```

this turn out recursive retrieval feature, level is used to limited to only 1 step (i.e. only links in given page), accept to specify acceptable suffixes (in this case only `hdf`). Not tested as I do not have access to said files. See [`wget` manpage](https://linux.die.net/man/1/wget) for details.

Comment: maybe, we need a ```=``` between ```--accept``` and ```hdf```.  ```wget --recursive --level=1 --accept=hdf https://e4ftl01.cr.usgs.gov/MOLT/MOD17A2H.006/2020.01.01/ ```

Comment: @ChaoLi man page which I linked does not stipulate `=` after `--accept`